# Deja-dup everytime creates a fresh first backup

Tags: 18.04, backup, snap, restore, deja-dup

Whenever I execute `/snap/bin/deja-dup --backup`, dejadup ask me for the password and creates backup for the first time (in Google drive). This happens even after the full backup has successfully completed! The next time it completely removes the old full backup and behaves as if it is backing up for the first time.

- Configuration:

```bsh
$ deja-dup --version
deja-dup 38.4

$  lsb_release -a
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

$ type deja-dup
deja-dup is hashed (/snap/bin/deja-dup)
```

[image: Backup Schedule]

[image: Screenshot: Asks for password everytime]

[image: Screenshot: Creates first backup everytime]

What can I do to avoid this?

Comment: Try the non-snap version.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Non snap version is not upto date and has several issues.

Comment: It works though.

Comment: For me it kept asking the password repeatedly (screenshot: as shown in the question.)